# New to Ubuntu USB Live - Changes don't save + Full memory of usb drive not utilized

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, usb

I've used ubuntu a few years ago. I replaced my windows operating system with it, but I think my computer wasn't compatible (it was a Toshiba something) with it because the fan wouldn't work, it kept overheating and wouldn't stay on form more than 15 minutes at a time.

This time, I decided to install it on a USB drive since I'll be able to utilize all of it's benefits that way without risking my current computer and still having the Windows OS for other things.

I bought a 128GB flash drive that I installed ubuntu on and I'm able to boot up the OS and work on it fine. The problem is that any updates I install don't save for the next session. I also am unable to utilize the full storage capacity of my flash drive.

My issues:

1. Even though when I originally burned the iso image into my drive I specified that I wanted persistent storage (3xxx MB of it). I used the software liveusb-creator. I had originally installed it for fedora but since it basically did the same thing, I also used it for ubuntu. However, I installed emacs the last time I used ubuntu, but when I booted it up now, it wasn't there.
2. I want to be able to use 128GB on my flash drive to store everything I do when I'm on ubuntu. All of the softwares and updates and programs and settings I choose.

How do I go about doing this? I looked at several sources online, but they don't address my issues exactly or they're hard to understand.

One source was talking about partitions, but I don't even know how to start with that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, copy the Ubuntu ISO to a different USB stick

Then, boot from a live CD, and after it boots, connect both flash drives; the one that you want to install to, and the one with the ISO.

Then, go Dash > Startup disk creator.

Point it to your ISO file on the one flash stick, and tell it to install to the other. You can adjust the slider for docs and settings to the max.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wish I could vote up your response, but apparently I need "15 reputation" first. When I end up getting it, I'll come back to do it then.